# how to draw end line on x axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts stacked bar chart, but not getting the lines at the end of values as it is in below image, can someone help me on this using Highcharts in built API or methods. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3AVm.png

Comment: Please share your code first.

Comment: Pirate X, i attached image for reference please look into it and let me know

Comment: Could you try to format your question to readable format? I think that you can use line Series for making similar lines to what you would like to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/rdw79x7p/

Comment: thanks Grzegorz Blachliński, and the thing is when i am trying to write the data on stack, value coming trice, attached image at the top

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can avoid that situation by disabling dataLabels of your line series: http://jsfiddle.net/rdw79x7p/3/

Comment: Thanks again, sorry for making you confused. but this time in single image I added all my  requirements in steps,

Comment: jsfiddle link here - https://jsfiddle.net/Sujay_KR/k73czb7b/

Answer (score 0):

create image and change the sun.png in js code.

```js
$(function () {


    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Combination chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                style: {
                    left: '50px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
            plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            name: 'John',
            data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
        }, {
            data: [9, 8, 9, 19, 10],
            lineWidth: 0,
            enableMouseTracking: false,

            marker: {
                    symbol:                'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                }         
               
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Dogru, on hovering to the sun, path is coming, how to avoid that?

Comment: Use enableMouseTracking: false as above;